# dynamic css class in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have following situation:

json:

```
[{"id":1,"prio":3},
{"id":2,"prio":3},
{"id":3,"prio":3},
{"id":4,"prio":4},
{"id":5,"prio":2}]
```

HTML/Angular

```
<ul ng-repeat>
<li class="high">{{id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Now my goal is to change the css class automatically depending on the attribute 'prio'.

```
When prio = 1 --> css= "low"
when prio = 2 --> css = "medium"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ngClass`:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in arr" ng-class="{low: item.prio === 1, medium: item.prio === 2}">{{id}}</li>
</ul>
```