# Angular: dynamic CSS behaviour

Tags: css, angular

I have an Angular 6 application that can run in different modes. The mode does have an impact regarding the CSS.

e.g. user-mode has blue borders around divs which have a help-topic; admin-mode has red-borders around buttons that change data; ...

The mode is set in the application itself (e.g. by a button).

Most of other parts of the CSS are generally the same for any mode.

How can I handle that?

Can I put angular-code (e.g. ngIf) in CSS?

I do not like to put a lot of [ngClass] with ifs in my templates as it is decribed here: [dynamic css class in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543535/dynamic-css-class-in-angular).

I would prefer a centralized handling - like mark any help-topic with a class and mark any admin-topic with a class and make the CSS react to the mode.

Comment: you don't need to put a lot of [ngClass]. Use only one as a wrapper.

Comment: If I have 20 divs and 3 of them have to be treated for help and 5 for admin then I have to put 8 [ngClass].

Comment: anyway, you can't put angular code in css.

Comment: Is there a way to select the used CSS dynamically? I know only the static way of selecting a CSS file per application or per component.

Comment: https://shekhargulati.com/2018/01/16/dynamically-loading-css-in-angular-5-application/ ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to put angular code in css. But you can do something like this:

html:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'firstClass': isActive, 'secondClass': !isActive}">
    <span>Hello world</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.firstClass span{
    color: red;
}

.secondClass span{
    color: green;
}
```